# Android NullPointerException when using setDataSource with a URI

Tags: java, android

Hey guys I'm making a music player for android and when I go to select a song to play the app crashes and produces the error:

```
09-16 13:10:08.671: I/System.out(22932): Reset worked
09-16 13:10:08.671: I/System.out(22932): com.example.taptwisttunes.Song@42d97240
09-16 13:10:08.671: I/System.out(22932): about to load song
09-16 13:10:08.671: I/System.out(22932): content://media/external/audio/media/23657
09-16 13:10:08.671: I/System.out(22932): content://media/external/audio/media/23657
09-16 13:10:08.671: D/AndroidRuntime(22932): Shutting down VM
09-16 13:10:08.671: W/dalvikvm(22932): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fee700)
09-16 13:10:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22932): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 13:10:08.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22932): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

Here is my playSong method does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong:

```
public void playSong(){ //this method plays the song by retrieving ID and modeling it as uri
        //player.reset(); //resets media player
        System.out.println("Reset worked");
        Song playSong = songs.get(sPos); // retrieves song to be played
        System.out.println(playSong);
        long currSong = playSong.getId();
        System.out.println("about to load song");
        Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, currSong);  
        System.out.println(trackUri);
        System.out.println(trackUri.toString());
        //try block not sure if uri will work as a data source

        try{
            player.setDataSource(this.getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Music Service", "There has been an error setting the data source", e);
        } 
        player.prepareAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the entire stack? You usually get this error when you try to execute a method on a `MediaPlayer` at a wrong state. Follow this [diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`MediaPlayer#prepareAsync`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync%28%29) throws `IllegalStateException`, you need to handle that exception or add throws to your method declaration, so the caller of the method will handle that. Did you do that?
something like :

```
try{
player.prepareAsync();
}
catch(IllegalStateException ise){
//do what you want when this exception is thrown
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the error and the code given, I believe you have called the `player` instance to play some song before and you are trying to play the song the second time.

Also you have commented out the `player.reset().`

Make sure, your `player` instance is **reset()**, **prepared()** and set to play the file correctly.

The [following diagram from the android developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), should help you understand the concept better.
[image]